# Why is integral operator not a local operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

My textbook says:

Define the integral operator $I: C^\infty([a,b]) \rightarrow C^\infty([a,b])$ by: $I(f) = \int_a^b f(t)dt$. Here $I(f)$ is a number, which we view as a constant function on $[a,b]$. The integral is not a local operator, since the value of $I(f)$ at any point $p$ depends on the values of $f$ over the entire interval $[a,b]$.

In this context, what is this point $p$? Is $p \in [a,b]$? But $I(f)$ is a fixed number, and $p \in [a,b]$ plays no role in determining the value of $I(f)$.

Comment: So? The value $I(f)$, though independent of $p$, still depends on the values of $f$ in the entire interval.

Comment: @Chrystomath Definition of local operator that I know is: whenever a $k$-form $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$ restricts to $0$ on an open set $U$ in $M$, then $D\omega \equiv 0$ on $U$. I don't see how I can use the definition to show that $I$ is not a local operator.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding the concept but I cannot identify what my misunderstanding is. This is my attempt. Assume by contradiction that $I$ is a local operator. Let $f \in C^\infty([a,b])$ and $f$ is locally 0 at $p \in (a,b)$. Say $f$ is zero in $U = (c,d) \in [a,b]$. Then, $I_U(f) = \int_c^d f = \int_c^d 0 = 0$.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but I don't think you should take $I_U$. What you should consider is $I(f)$ restricted to $U$. Thus $I(f)=\int_a^bf\ne0$ even though $f=0$ on $[c,d]$. Since $I(f)$ is constant it remains so even on $[c,d]$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example should make the argument clearer. For convenience take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and fix $f=1$ on $[0,1]$ so that $I(f)=1.$

The gist of this is that $I$ is an operator that takes a continuous function to a subset of the continuous functions on $[0,1],$ namely the constants. So, we are viewing $I(f)$ as a *function*, which we could write $I(f)(x)=1.$

Now define $g(x)=\begin{cases}1\quad 0\le x\le 1/4 \\
-2x+3/2\quad 1/4<x<3/4\\
0\quad 1/4\le x\le 1\end{cases}$

Then $g=f$ on $U=(0,1/4)$ but $(I(f))_U(x)=I(f)(x)=1$ and $(I(g))_U(x)=I(g)(x)=3/4.$

Comment: The function g is not in the domain of I.

Comment: Ups. I guess we can fix it though pretty easily.

Comment: To check non locality it is enough to observe that a function can vanish on an open subset U of [0,1] and at the same time to have zero integral in [0,1]

Comment: Zero integral? Non-zero right?

Comment: Yup ${}{}{}{}{}$